# Is it possible to reference a shared library (.so) via a static library (.a)

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, ld, static-linking

I want to (effectively) resolve references to symbols in multiple shared libraries by incorporating them into a static library and linking against the static library at compile time. I want to do this to simplify the build process across multiple builds - so that I only need to provide one static library for a build. The dynamic libs are available at run-time as normal. Is this possible?

So, currently I have (the usual way of doing things) created static.a which contains a number of objects with references to dyn1.so...dynN.so, and I can create prog.elf with:

```
ar rcs libstatic.a obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o  
gcc prog.o -l:libstatic.a -ldyn1 -ldyn2 -ldyn3 -o prog.elf
```

what I want to do is:

```
ar rcs libstatic.a obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o libdyn0.so libdyn1.so libdyn2.so  
gcc prog.o -l:libstatic.a -o prog.elf
```

I've tried the latter, and references to symbols in the .so files are not getting resolved, though those symbols do appear to be in libstatic.a, e.g.

objdump -TC  libstatic.a
...
00006ded g    DF .text  00000088  DLIB_1.0   func_data_new
...

Cheers!

Comment: Better specify your distro, GCC and binutils versions and provide an [mcve] of the
failing linkage with complete output. What you appear to be attempting works
for me, Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.3.0, binutils 2.30